# LocalStorage Anomalies in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I made a website which uses localStorage, but I mainly tested it in Opera.

The way the website gets the locally stored data is by using a JS for loop:

`for (var key in localStorage) {
    // DO STUFF! 
}`

When my friends used the website with chrome and firefox they told me it displays random strings.

Screens here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okfld.png (list on the left are the localstorage keys) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qz5C.png

My first assumption is that Chrome or Firefox added some localStorage items on each visit to the website (deleting the cookies doesn't fix the issue as they re-occur).

The problem is that when my website calls for the users/localStorage, it just says "get all cookie keys" and seems to get literally ALL, even the ones that the browsers create.

I can only think of 1 way to fix it, by just blocking all the keywords that chrome and firefox create within the JS itself, and forcing it not to be shown.

Any ideas? I know this is extremely specific but it is troublesome. additional info, I already checked the extensions they were using, but they don't seem to be the trouble (because I have the same one's and these localstorage anomalies aren't an issue).

Thanks to all responses and putting up with me :)

Also, my website if anyone else wishes to report more bugs:

http://youtube-collections.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` (and [avoid for-in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)):

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

## Example

```
var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
for(var i = 0, key; key = keys[i]; i++) {
   // use key, ie. getItem(key) ...
}
```

Comment: This worked. Is there any similar ways to check if the localstorage is from the webpage, and not from, say, a browser extension? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mathieu pointed out, localStorage is an object. To prevent it from happening use this:

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do stuff with it
    }
}
```

or use forEach methods from lodash (`_.forEach()`), jQuery (`jQuery.each()`) or angular (`angular.forEach()`).

Comment: Sorry if this is a super-noob question but what does are forEach methods?

Comment: Oh okay I figured it out for myself :D thanks for the main reply, this should work in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's because localStorage is an object. When you iterate over an object with the for loop you will get all properties from that object, including its methods.

Comment: As I said, this doesn't happen on Opera, so why does it occur on firefox and chrome? And is there any other fixes? Thank you for the reply by the way :)

Comment: I have no clue why it does work on Opera, but it shouldn't ;) @zwacky provided the rest of the answer while I was still looking, so take a look at that :)